# Using Coordinate Method to Solve the Inhomogeneous Constant Coefficient PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is a problem out of Strauss' book that in working on:

Solve $au_{x}+bu_{y}=f(x,y)$, where $f(x,y)$ is a given function. If $a \neq 0$, write the solution in the form

$u(x,y)=(a^{2}+b^{2})^{-1/2}\int_{L}f\,ds+g(bx-ay)$,

where $g$ is an arbitrary function of one variable, $L$ is the characteristic line segment from the $y$ axis to the point $(x,y)$, and the integral is a line integral ($s$ is a dummy variable). (Hint: Use the coordinate method.)

Now, using the coordinate method, with change of coordinates $x^{\prime}=ax+by$ and $y^{\prime}=bx-ay$, I can easily solve the homogeneous problem; I believe that that is where the $g(bx-ay)$ part comes from. It's just getting the particular solution, which I believe to equal $(a^{2}+b^{2})^{-1/2}\int_{L}f\,ds$, is what I am really having trouble with. Could somebody please let me know how to derive the particular solution? If so, it would be much appreciated!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE says: the directional derivative of $u$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction of $\langle a,b\rangle$ is equal to $(a^2+b^2)^{-1/2}f(x,y)$. Suppose we look for particular solution $f$ such that $f(0,y)=0$ for all $x$. Then for any   point $(x,y)$ we can obtain $f(x,y)$ by integrating the directiona derivative along the segment $L$ described in the problem -- this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus applied  on this segment. There is nothing else to the meaning of $(a^{2}+b^{2})^{-1/2}\int_{L}f\,ds$.